# How to check server is down when parsing json android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I develop android application which access and get value json from current website, the problem is how to check and give error message dialog sometimes the hosting of website is down, so I cannot get value json from its, is it possible? For example, if I dont have internet connection, then application will show error message "NO INTERNET CONNECTION". 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to check whether you are connected to internet or not
Call this method before you start json parsing
public static boolean isDeviceAvailable(Context context) {

```
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I dont have internet connection, then application will show error
>   message "NO INTERNET CONNECTION"

you should use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check if device is connected to Internet or not before making request to Web service.

> give error message dialog sometimes the hosting of website is down

Use `HttpURLConnection` for making WebService request with `HttpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout()` timeout property. like if timeout is set 2000sec for request then if no response from sever show appropriate message to user "Server is Down" .